# Orchard - From dashboard or VS

Tags: orchardcms, dashboard, orchardcms-1.6

following the tutorials on `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nq480A0pgqc&list=PL0-GOAU3tpMYm0F1CHYP5_egk0mmAGMab` for orchard cms.

Although all tutorials I find are using the dashboard to change the appearance of the site.
Is this the norm? I would like to learn to work from VS for this but cant find much on it....

any advice?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a starting point I would recommend Skywalker's excellent tutorial series. If you need to do it in orchard, it is in this series.

http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-1

On themes - they are changed from within Orchard, but developed outside it. VS is not necessary, but gives good intelli-sense on razor views.

The correct place to start on writing a new theme is here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-new-theme